# How is it possible my array is broken?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this piece of code:

```
public lot merge (lot otherlot){
    wafer[] mWaferarray = new wafer[16];
    byte[] bytearray = new byte[16];
    wafer resultwafer = new wafer(bytearray);
    wafer w1;
    wafer w2;
    int i;
    int[][] assignmentmatrix = HungarianAlgorithm.computeAssignments(convertinttofloat (solutionmatrix(otherlot)));

    for (i=0; i != assignmentmatrix.length ;i++){

        w1 = otherlot.getWaferarray()[assignmentmatrix[i][0]];

        w2 = getWaferarray()[assignmentmatrix[i][1]];


        resultwafer.setWafer(w1.wafercompare(w2));

        mWaferarray[i] = resultwafer;
        mWaferarray[i].print();



    }
    System.out.println("HERE\n");
    mWaferarray[5].toString();

    resultlot = new lot(mWaferarray);
    resultlot.print();// Problem occurs here.

    return resultlot;

}
```

As you can see I create an array of wafers (selfdefined class). Then I fill this up with new wafers. When I print this array (mWaferarray[i].print()) it gives me the wanted results. But when I go out of the "for"-loop the array is broken and it is as if the last item I add to mWaferarray fills it up (the entire array, 16 long, is filled with this wafer). 
So if run this program this is what I get:

```
1011110010111100
0011011111111110
0111110111101101
1010111001101111
0110110111101111
1010110101111010
1010110111011110
1011111010111100
1111110011101110
0111111111011011
1111111111011010
1101111011111010
1010110101011110
0101111011011010
1011111011011000
0101111011011010
HERE

0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
0101111011011010
```

As you can see it is as if the array is filled with the last wafer.

I have been looking at this for some time now, I hope you guy can help me out.

Thx in advance

PS: my print functions are written like this:

```
    void print(){
    int j;
    for (j=0; j != waferarray.length ;j++){
        waferarray[j].print();

        }


    }
```

EDIT: added code for lot

this is the beginning of the lot class

```
public class lot {


wafer[] waferarray = new wafer[16];
lot resultlot;

public lot (wafer wafer1,wafer wafer2,wafer wafer3,wafer wafer4,
        wafer wafer5,wafer wafer6,wafer wafer7,wafer wafer8,
        wafer wafer9,wafer wafer10,wafer wafer11,wafer wafer12,
        wafer wafer13,wafer wafer14,wafer wafer15,wafer wafer16){

    waferarray[0] = wafer1;
    waferarray[1] = wafer2;
    waferarray[2] = wafer3;
    waferarray[3] = wafer4;
    waferarray[4] = wafer5;
    waferarray[5] = wafer6;
    waferarray[6] = wafer7;
    waferarray[7] = wafer8;
    waferarray[8] = wafer9;
    waferarray[9] = wafer10;
    waferarray[10] = wafer11;
    waferarray[11] = wafer12;
    waferarray[12] = wafer13;
    waferarray[13] = wafer14;
    waferarray[14] = wafer15;
    waferarray[15] = wafer16;


}

public lot (wafer[] thiswaferarray){

    waferarray = thiswaferarray;


}
```

Comment: what is "lot"? can you put in some more code..

Comment: How much actually did you debug your code yourself before deciding to ask us help? Did you add debug printing statements to each assignment? Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: You are probably adding the same wafer every time. Remember that java works by reference so doing `x = new ...; a = x; b = x; x.setSomething("q");` will change **both** a **and** b.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it happens like this?

```
resultlot = new lot(mWaferarray); // Problem actually occurs in the constructor you did not show us
resultlot.print();// Problem only manifests itself here.
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with the constructor, I added him above

Comment: +1 When you create an array it is an array of *references* which are all `null` by default.  To have an array which is populated in Java you have to assign a new object to each reference.  If you do not, you have no object to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some kind of homework :-)

The Problem is this :

```
    resultwafer.setWafer(w1.wafercompare(w2));

    mWaferarray[i] = resultwafer;
    mWaferarray[i].print();
```

you are reusing resultwafer, only the contents of ruseultwafer is changed / replaced.

In the end all elements of the mWaferarray point to the same resultwafer instance and it shows only the contents sets in the lass loop.

To fix this you have to create new wafers (and possibly new bytearrays) in the loop.